# Unknown locale UTF-8 when installing MsSQL server on ubuntu

Tags: python, locale, mssql

I'm trying to install `Ms SQL Server` on `ubuntu 17.10`, I run commands step by step:

```
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -

sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017.list)"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

and when I run setup command:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 277, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 273, in main
processCommands()
File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 197, in processCommands
COMMAND_TABLE[args.which]()
File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 54, in handleSetup
exit(mssqlconfhelper.setupSqlServer(eulaAccepted, noprompt=args.noprompt))
File "/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/mssqlconfhelper.py", line 817, in setupSqlServer
languageSelect(noprompt)
File "/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/mssqlconfhelper.py", line 160, in languageSelect
language = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 545, in getdefaultlocale
return _parse_localename(localename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 477, in _parse_localename
raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

`locale` command outputs:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
root@ubuntu-mssql-server:~#
```

what might be the solution?

Comment: Do you log in to the server from a macOS machine?

Comment: @gunnar yes, I'm logging from macos terminal using ssh

Comment: Ok. `UTF-8` is an invalid locale name on Ubuntu, and probably you export a locale variable to that name when logging in. Does possibly the file `~/.ssh/environment` exist which sets some locale variable to `UTF-8`?

Comment: There's no dir ~/.ssh/environment

Comment: Then can you please show us the output of the `locale` command (by editing your question).

Comment: sure, added ......

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I suggest that you open the `~/.profile` file for editing and add the line:

```
unset LC_CTYPE
```

That ought to compensate for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from other forums I found that if you change the local variable named "LC_ALL", it has to be set to the following value: `en_US.UTF-8`.

The way to do this is to execute the following command as root:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```